# web api - commit database transaction in action filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

**Edit:** This question has been modified completely from its original version.

My objective is to commit the database transaction at the action filer level. I am using Web API .Net Framework (4.8) along with Unity DI.

My Transaction Filter Attribute:

```
public class TransactionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly PortalContext _context;
    private DbContextTransaction _transactionScope;

    public TransactionFilterAttribute(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _context = container.Resolve<PortalContext>();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        _transactionScope = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        using (_transactionScope)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            _transactionScope.Commit(); //Error occurred
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Unity Configuration:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;

    private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<PortalContext>();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error while executing `_transactionScope.Commit()`

**Error:** Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connection --> The underlying provider failed on Commit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to look something like this. This would open the transaction when the controller gets called and would wait for the method to return before committing the transaction. This is done by the "await next()" part. You should resolve the _databaseContext from your IOC container so make sure to add it at startup. Using a service filter allows you to use the IOC container within a filter. Have a look at this post to learn more about implementing a service filter in .NET projects: https://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/. The example below it made for an async method, use the sync version of this method if needed.

```
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        using (var transaction = _champContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = await next();
            if ((result.Exception == null || result.ExceptionHandled) &&
                IsHttpSuccessStatusCode(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode))
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                return;
            }

            transaction.Rollback();
            var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            var controllerName = controllerActionDescriptor?.ControllerName;
            var actionName = controllerActionDescriptor?.ActionName;

            _logger.Error("Tried to commit transaction for the {ActionName}" +
                          " method on the {ControllerName} controller with the following parameters: {ActionParameters}" +
                          " but got exception: {Exception}",
                actionName, controllerName, context.ActionArguments, result.Exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not appliable in the .net framework. `OnActionExecutionAsync` is available in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a guess, but I'm wondering if the `using` clause in your `OnActionExecuting` override is to blame.

As soon as the base call to OnActionExecuting returns, your _transactionScope is Dispose'd. Thus, assuming that OnActionExecuted isn't called from within the base.OnActionExecuting method, _transactionScope will not be in the state you're expecting in OnActionExecuted.

Suggest:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    _transactionScope = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        _transactionScope.Commit(); //Error occurred
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        _transactionScope.Rollback(); // because something went wrong during your transaction
    }
    finally
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose(); // now that we're definitely done.
    }
}
```